# PHPmailer sending 3 times Email with 1 attachment

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer, joomla3.0

i got a problem and i cant find any solution.

When customers shop with me on the site, they come to a thank you page. Since we send with phpmailer an email with attachment invoice. The email is however unfortunately sent 3 times and only once with attachment and the correct parameter. The other two mails are naked without price without address without name without attachment.

PHPmail code:

```
    <?php

require_once (JPATH_ROOT.'/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once (JPATH_ROOT.'/PHPMailer/language/phpmailer.lang-de.php');




$mail = new PHPMailer; 
$mail->From = 'info@picknstick.de'; 
$mail->FromName = 'pickNstick'; 
$mail->addAddress($arr["email"]); 
$mail->addReplyTo('info@picknstick.de'); 
$mail->addCC('info@picknstick.de'); 
$mail->isHTML(true); // Mail als HTML versenden 
$mail->Subject = 'pickNstick-Rechnung'; 
$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'rechnung/'.$pdfName, 'Rechnung_pickNstick.pdf');
$mail->Body = 

'
Hallo <b>'.$arr["nachname"].' '.$arr["name"].'</b>,
<hr>
'; 


if(!$mail->send()) { 
    echo 'Mail wurde nicht abgesendet'; 
    echo 'Fehlermeldung: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
} else { 
    echo 'Rechnung wurder per Email nochmals an Sie verschickt !'; 
}

?>
```

I think my Code works and there is nothing wrong...

Why is Joomla sending this mail 3 Times ?

www.picknstick.de <--- Online - Shop

How/Where can i search for this Problem ?

Comment: Where is this code located inside of Joomla? The code looks fine, but might be located in a place where Joomla is looping and doing other things as well, causing it to be called 3 times.

Comment: Its on a Article in joomla backend i wrote it there...

Comment: You're not doing any kind of checking if the data you're getting has actually been submitted, you're just sending every time it hits the page, so I'm not in the least surprised.

Comment: something is calling it three times, which you've already worked out. Nothing in the code you've shown above is causing that. Therefore the problem is somewhere else. Without more context we don't know what's going on, and the question is essentially un-answerable. If this is really the whole of your page code though, then anyone/anything requesting that page will cause an email to be sent. But I suspect this isn't the whole story because otherwise there would be undefined variables.

Comment: How can i Search or See all request? So Maybe i can Look for more Details ...

Comment: @Synchro How can i fix this ? With Session ? I am using simple caddy and there you can checkout dierectly dont Need to register! Or with catch .../thank-you?Data=xxxxx in the URL ?

Comment: @ADyson How can i Search or See all request? So Maybe i can Look for more Details ...

Comment: if it's contained within a function, search for code that can call that function, and then work out if that code calls it too many times, or that code itself can
 be called multiple times. Or if it's triggered directly by a URL, then look in your webserver logs to see when it was called and how many times and by who. Maybe see if it's called by some Javascript/ajax that is running too many times. I don't know - like I said there's no context so it could be anything. You need to debug your application, basically. It's a useful skill to learn.

Comment: okay Thank you i will look for it tomorrow :)